# MySQLSyntaxErrorException error in Like clause

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this function, which gets a List of objects from MySQL, using the like clause, but when testing, returns me a error of MySQLSyntaxErrorException, what i should do?

### Code

```
    @Override
    public List<Livro> getLista(String nm) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Livro> lista = new ArrayList<Livro>();

        try {
            String query= "SELECT L.*, nmautor, nmeditora FROM tblivro L, tbeditora E,tbautor A "
                    + "WHERE nmlivro LIKE ? and L.cdautor = A.cdautor and L.cdeditora = E.cdeditora ";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            String like = "%"+nm+"%";
            stmt.setString(1, like);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            ...
    }}
```

---

### Full Error

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'a' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2546)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1370)
        at biblioc.dados.LivroDAO.getLista(LivroDAO.java:387)
```

Comment: Did you check the manual from `MariaDB` ?

Comment: did you crosscheck table and column names? Maybe run that query manually once? Maybe you could setup a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: The query successfully executed successfully on the phpMyAdmin and the tables/column names are ok

Comment: @LucasSilvaChaves Doesn't `phpMyAdmin` use `MySQL` ? There might be a difference between this and `MariaDB`'s syntax.

Comment: My phpMyAdmin runs MariaDB http://imgur.com/qhET1Iz

Comment: @LucasSilvaChaves What is the meaning of `LIKE ?`. What are you trying to achieve with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Replace this with

```
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

To execute a SQL string with JDBC, you only need to pass the SQL string to JDBC once, and when you are using a PreparedStatement that one time is when you prepare the statement.  Once you've set all the parameters, calling `executeQuery()` with no arguments will run the prepared statement with the parameter values you set.

Calling the version of `executeQuery` that takes a single string parameter will run the SQL in that string, without allowing you to use any parameter values.  This is because the PreparedStatement interface inherits this method from the Statement interface.

This behaviour of the MySQL JDBC driver is particularly confusing.  You are far from being the first person to make this mistake and wonder what is going on, and I cannot believe that you will be the last.  As pointed out in the comments, the JDBC driver is supposed to throw an exception when you call `executeQuery` with a string on a PreparedStatement.  Had it done so, you may well have found a solution to your problem much quicker.

I don't know what your variable `sql` is.  Perhaps it just contains a single letter `a` - I was able to reproduce your error message by running `stmt.executeQuery("a")`.

Comment: It is a bug in the MySQL driver that it even allows you to call `executeQuery(String)` on a prepared or callable statement (passing a query without parameters would have succeeded). The JDBC specification requires a driver to throw an `SQLException` always if this method is called on `PreparedStatement` and `CallableStatement`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: thanks, I didn't know that.  I've updated my answer to clarify that it's not general JDBC behaviour.  Funnily enough the Oracle JDBC driver has the same bug.